# Is there a way to get the thread-id in Selenium Webdriver Sampler for JMeter?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, webdriver, jmeter-plugins

I need to get the id/number of the actual thread in my Webdriver Sampler code.
Is there a way to identify the thread the code is run from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `WDS.ctx` shorthand which stands for [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html) class instance so you should be able to use [getThreadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html#getThreadNum--) function in order to obtain current thread (virtual user) number:

```
var threadID = WDS.ctx.getThreadNum()
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered/)

Answer (score 1):

Use [threadNum](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) or [ThreadGroupName](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadGroupName) which ever suits your purpose. Please check  the below snapshot for using it in webdriver sampler;-

[image]

Hope this helps.